# Get data to my Google Drive

Tags: google-earth-engine, google

I can't get the data to my Google Drive, see the code below:

```
var image = ee.Image(ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR")
.filterBounds(roi)
.filterDate('2018-05-01', '2018-05-30')
.sort('CLOUD_COVER')
.first());
Map.addLayer(image, {bands:['B3', 'B2', 'B1'], min:0, max: 3000}, 'True colour image');

var geometry = ee.Geometry. Rectangle(roi);


Export.image.toAsset({
  image: image,
  description: 'image_seoul',
  scale: 30,
  region: geometry,
  maxPixels: 4020250081,
  crs: 'EPSG:5186'
});
```

Comment: Hi user155885, Welcome to GIS StackExchange, I edit your post (no smiley and "I" in the title) and edit your code as code, maybe you could explain a bit more about what you're doing and what's your problem ? Thank you

Comment: I mean I can't export my data

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Image exportToDrive in Google Earth Engine?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/312324/using-image-exporttodrive-in-google-earth-engine)

Answer (score 1):

`Export.image.toAsset()` exports to an EE asset. It will end up under your left-hand-side "Assets" tab. To export to Google Drive you `Export.image.toDrive()`. To ensure your bands have compatible data types, you might need to cast the image, e.g. `image.int16()`.

```
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: image.int16().clip(roi),
  description: 'image_seoul',
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 4020250081,
  crs: 'EPSG:5186'
});
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/15c3a54eb4ce0799a5909d42f6354024